# creating WCF operation invoker

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-rest

How can I created following model in resfull wcf service

Operation Behaviour invokes the custom operation invoker which performs the validations based on the inputs/values passed in header of the Http request. On successful validation, users will be redirected to the actual operation. Otherwise custom exception will be thrown and users will be redirected to the ‘Access Denied’ page.

Comment: Do you have to do it this way? (i.e. via an Operation Behavior)? Can't you use a decorator? Or maybe an AOP aspect?

Comment: I am not aware of any of the 3 ways.Please provide me a link to read on that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve custom validation is through a service [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Consider the following code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}

public class ServiceValidationDecorator : IService
{
    private readonly IService m_DecoreatedService;

    public ServiceValidationDecorator(IService decoreated_service)
    {
        m_DecoreatedService = decoreated_service;
    }

    public string GetData(int value)
    {

        IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;

        WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;

        //Here use the headers to do you custom validation
        bool valid = ...

        if(!valid)
            throw new SecurityException("Access Denied");

        return m_DecoreatedService.GetData(value);
    }
}
```

Here, the WCF contract is IService, and the original service implementation is the Service class.

The ServiceValidationDecorator class is a decorator that does the custom validation and then passes the request to another service.

Now instead of hosting the Service class, you need to host the ServiceValidationDecorator class.

WCF is going to complain that the ServiceValidationDecorator does not have a parameterless constructor. The correct way to fix this is to create a custom Instance Provider (take a look at [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wcf/Composing-WCF-applications.aspx)), and then construct the ServiceValidationDecorator object (within the instance provider)  like this:

```
new ServiceValidationDecorator(new Service())
```

If you want a quick workaround just to quickly test this, simple construct the Service class in the ServiceValidationDecorator constructor (this is actually a bad design practice).

If you have many services and you don't want to create a decorator for each service, take a look at Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP). Search for PostSharp or DynamicProxy.